# Is ROS2 fully functional on windows?

Tags: windows, ros, ros2

I am aware that ROS can partially be used in windows or mac. But can the newer variant, ROS2, be used in windows fully?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ROS2 is fully supported on Linux, Windows and MacOS.